# How to prevent socket exhaustion on http requests?

Tags: python, http

I'm a .NET developer writing a python client which needs to do multiple HTTP requests in a short amount of time.

In .NET, when you use HttpClient to make a request, it opens a socket connection to make the request and get the response. When you're done with the HttpClient and dispose it, the socket isn't immediately closed. Instead, it's left in a state called TIME_WAIT, in which it waits to see if any more packets from the same connection arrive. This is standard behavior for TCP/IP and is designed to ensure all packets are received before closing the connection.

However, this has a side effect: sockets in the TIME_WAIT state still count against your machine’s maximum limit of open sockets, which is a finite resource. The length of the TIME_WAIT period varies depending on the OS, but it’s usually around 4 minutes.

As a result, using a HTTPClientFactory is recommended to manage instances of http clients.

How is this problem handled in python, using the requests module? What is best practice?

Comment: I doubt it does anything special. Most applications don't send so many requests that they run out of ports before the TIME_WAIT sockets time out.

Comment: Every modern operating system is capable of handling tens of thousands of simultanous sockets by default. If it is not enough for you then either you have some very fancy use case, or more likely you are doing something wrong. This is not a real problem. .Net platform (which in general I think is superior to Python) makes this particular thing unnecessarily convoluted. Just open sockets and make sure you are not opening more than say 1000 at given time and you will be fine. It is unlikely you will be able to efficiently process that much anyway.

Comment: Its a real issue, and I already came across it from time to time in e.g test systems executing lots of tests in parallel. But I agree, in productive apps its less common.